# grouping and Update Property in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a Collection of Objects of the following

```
class Stream
{
    string PeriodName {set;get;}
    string StreamName{set;get;}
    string Index{set;get;}
}
```

There Could be N repeating stream  under different Period Name, Like

```
PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Oil"

PeriodName ="B"
StreamName ="Oil"

PeriodName ="C"
StreamName ="Oil"

PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Petrol"

PeriodName ="B"
StreamName ="Petrol"

PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Diesel"
```

i want to Group these objects by StreamName and insert the Index Number.
Expected Result is

```
PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Oil"
Index=1

PeriodName ="B"
StreamName ="Oil"
Index=1

PeriodName ="C"
StreamName ="Oil"
Index=1

PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Petrol"
Index=2

PeriodName ="B"
StreamName ="Petrol"
Index=2

PeriodName ="A"
StreamName ="Diesel"
Index=3
```

How can i achieve the same in C#?

Answer (score 2):

```
list =list.GroupBy(l=>l.StreamName )
   .SelectMany((g,index) => g.Select(x=>
                    new Stream(){
                        PeriodName =x.PeriodName, 
                        StreamName =x.StreamName, 
                        Index =(index+1).ToString()})).ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer will index each group not the elements inside each one! This question exactly wants the elements to be grouped by PeriodName, then inside each group, the index should be updated based on the count of the elements in that group.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to update the `Index` of existing objects rather than creating new ones, You can go with this,

```
streamList = streamList.GroupBy(stream => stream.StreamName)
             .SelectMany((streamGroup, index) => streamGroup.Select(stream =>
             {
                 stream.Index = index+1;
                 return stream;
             })).ToList();
```